# How can I find out which cards are supported by the fglrx driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, repository, fglrx

I want to know where I can find out which is the current fglrx-updates driver in the repo. I own a Radeon R9 270 and I need to know if it is supported since Trusty 14.04. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) I found from the unofficial AMD Linux community.

Here's the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fglrx#Linux) on Wikipedia.

You can also search about your driver on the AMD website, see if works for Linux.

The unofficial AMD Linux community hasn't provided an installation tutorial on Trusty Tahr yet. I'm kind of itchy about trying the 13.10 installation method.

From my own experience with Precise and Saucy, the current release 13.12 didn't work very well on both platform but the 14.3 beta worked sort of fine for me, but still caused some crashes when I was using VLC. After I switched to Trusty Tahr, the CPU fan is very quiet and the laptop isn't hot as fire without the Catalyst driver, unlike the previous releases.

I am using a DELL INSPIRON N5010 laptop and running on the Mobility Radeon HD5650 graphic card, for your information.

Comment: Found your driver here, http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64. So Catalyst 13.12 support the Desktop card Radeon R9 270. The installation procedure on the unofficial AMD linux community website is universal. I haven't tested it yet but I recommend trying the beta release. Good luck.

Comment: I've tried the new 14.04 release. Works fine so far.